# How do I find this parse error reported by Firebug after YUI compression?

Tags: javascript, yui-compressor

I have a website that uses Javascript. In my home testing environment, the Javascript is contained in a number of different files. When I upload the files to the live site, I use a Bash script to combine and compress the files so the site is overall more efficient.

First I combine the Javascript files using `cat`:

```
cat list_of_javascript_files_to_combine.txt | xargs cat > combined_javascript_file.js
```

Then I use YUI Compressor to compress the resulting Javascript:

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar combined_javascript_file.js -o combined_javascript_file.js --charset utf-8
```

In my local testing environment, before the Javascript is combined and compressed, it works without reporting any errors at all.

However, after uploading, when I look at the console in Firebug, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
...|0)}}this._yuifacade=true;this._event=z;this.pageX=t;this.pageY=w;x=z.keyCode||z...
```

The problem is that because the javascript is compressed, everything is on one long line, making it nearly impossible to determine where the error is in the pre-compressed files. Also, it's not at all certain that the snippet of code Firebug is showing me is where the error actually is. I have, of course, searched for the part of the string displayed, but it doesn't look erroneous to me, and Netbeans, which I use to Debug, doesn't report any warnings for where that code is.

Since this error only seems to appear after I compress the Javascript, I assume there's something about the compression itself that is causing trouble. However, the resulting compressed file is, by design, really hard for a human like me to parse, making debugging a little beyond my abilities.

Is there a way I can narrow down what the problem is so that I can fix it?